# Convert a Table with master Child Relation to XML/SiteMap

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, xml, sitemap

[image]

I have a Table like this .Where Menu PK is the ParentID of another MenuText.Is there a way that I can convert this to a XML /or sitemap(using ado.net preferably ) so that I can use it for Databinding a Menu Control.

What I had tried is a recursive function to create menuItem for each child found under each Menutext

There are Mulitple level of Hierrachy .Can anyone suggest an idea

Comment: I think you can use joins in sql and convert it to xml (eg:select * from table1 FOR XML AUTO) then u can bind

Comment: What's wrong with a recursive approach? Such a hierarchy will need some kind of recursion... Are you looking for a C# or SQL solution?
 Please do not paste a picture! Do you expect us to type this in? Best is a MCVE with some `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT INTO` commands. Add the expected output and what you've tried so far. Please read [How to create a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry Shungo  . I had used recursive C# function to create the menu items. but doing it each time makes system very slow.so i decide to create XML/sitemap  .I was not trying to get a code . I was trying to get a suggestion or idea thats why i didnt added code ..